# drupal8: How to install modules?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Hi i need to develop a site with a headless drupal and react.

I'm new to drupal, install is ok, site is running locally.

now i need to install rest ui

but I got this message when i ty to install the module

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 406
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php?batch=1&id=7&op=do_nojs&op=do
>   StatusText: Not Acceptable
>   ResponseText: {"message":"No route found for the specified format json. Supported formats: html."}

Same problem trying to install devel

- What route does it refer to?
- Format of what?

Googling about drupal drives me nuts.. hope someone could help!

Drupal Version
**8.8.5**

Web Server
PHP **7.1.16** Development Server

Comment: What version of `restui`, https://www.drupal.org/project/restui ?

Comment: same problem with every versions

Answer (score 0):

You could use composer to do this and install the module as composer package.

Example if you want to install this module https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_sitemap you could do it using this command in the terminal:

```
composer require 'drupal/simple_sitemap:^3.6'
```

After this you will be able to see this module in the list of available modules in your admin panel and you will be able to install it without any problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

Update to true allow_authorize_operations in your settings.php Drupal 8

```
$settings['allow_authorize_operations'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal you have two ways for installing modules:

(1) Copy files via FTP or something similar to your server

(2) Use the build-in function, in this case the webserver needs write access to the module diretories.

Check: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/extending-drupal-8/installing-drupal-8-modules